# Has MaxMind's GeoLiteCity IP geocoding database been reduced in accuracy?

Tags: geocoding

I took a copy of MaxMind's free city-level geocoding database a year or so ago, and the file size was roughly 30MB.

Checking [their site](http://www.maxmind.com/app/geolite) again today (July 2012), the equivalent file is now only 17MB, approximately half the size.

I cannot find any reference to this online. Does anyone know if they've reduced the quality or range of their free offering, or whether it's just an improvement in the binary encoding/layout of the data that resulted in the smaller file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like they offer fewer countries now than they used to.

Current: http://www.maxmind.com/app/geolite_city_accuracy

Snapshot from December 2010: http://web.archive.org/web/20101207175639/http://www.maxmind.com/app/geolite_city_accuracy

For example, I no longer see Uruguay, Venezuela, or Vietnam on the list.

Comment: That's great. Thanks very much. Some of the accuracy figures have changed too, both with some values increasing and others decreasing.